# Update user profile in Django

Tags: python, django, crud

I wanted to make an update profile function where users can update their data by filling out a form. My website is running well without any errors, but whenever I fill up the form & hit submit the profile doesn't update itself & also new data is not saved. Here is the code:

```
views.py:

def updateProfile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    profile_form = updateProfile(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
    if profile_form.is_valid():
        profile_form.save()
        return redirect('profile')
else:
    profile_form = UserProfile(instance=request.user.profile)
return render(request, 'profile.html', {'profile_form': profile_form})
```

Please check out my function.

Comment: Where is code of your form ?

Comment: Did you debug where the control reaches ? Is it even going inside the if condition ? Also i would suggest using class based views rather than function based